# Displaying lists in html page using arduino

Tags: html, c++, loops, arduino, arduino-esp8266

Can anyone please help me by suggesting a best way to create lists in an html page from an arduino code?
As the content in the each list element may change, my idea was to create lists using a loop.

As i am new to html and arduino coding, anyone having idea on creating lists of varying inputs in html page through arduino code, Please let me know.

Thank for the support in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

The principle would be:
Host html on SPIFFS
Create values on the Arduino
Fill the html on the relevant places with the code
As a starting example look at file browser NG example for Arduino esp8266. Here they create lists of the files on spiffs and display them in the browser. https://github.com/gmag11/FSBrowser 
Stay with the old non library version as a starter its easier to understand and modify,